# Ruby, MongoDB, don't complain about undefined methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

So I'm using MongoDB in an app and the fields for my documents have grown but In my views I don't want to have to have like an `if` block for each attribute, how can I have rails just display the value of the attribute if it is exists otherwise just quietly do nothing?

---

Example:

Since Mongo is schema-less these values wouldn't be defined in earlier instances of my models.

```
<%= @company.address %>
<%= @company.longitude %>
<%= @company.latitude %>
```

How do I handle this?

Comment: Are you using the MongoDB Ruby Driver or any kind of ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to just cope, you can always implement your own `method_missing` on that class which just eats calls and returns `nil`:

```
class Company
  def method_missing(*args)
    nil
  end
end
```

This could sweep a number of problems under the carpet, so you probably want to be careful when doing this sort of thing.

You could also make an extension that lets you do this:

```
= @company.try_method(:address)
```

This will return `nil` if there is no `address` method if you add this in an initializer:

```
class Object
  def try_method(method, *args)
    respond_to?(method) ? send(method, *args) : nil
  end
end
```

The `try` method that's part of Rails will only work if a method may return `nil`, but not if the method is not defined.

Comment: I guess what I'm wondering is that with all these document based ORM's which are all largely schema-less, isn't this a growing issue that more and more people are having? Great answer by the way.

Comment: I haven't done too much with them, but I'd bet you're supposed to use them as you might a Hash with the `[]` accessor instead of the JavaScript method-style. In JavaScript `object.arbitrary` is safely `null` by default, whereas in Ruby it is an undefined method call.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoid supports [field default values](http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/fields.html).

```
class Company
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :address, type: String, default: ""
end
```

Comment: The view doesn't care what you give it so long as you can convert it to a string safely. The result of `<%= (expr) %>` is always `(expr).to_s` and conveniently enough `nil.to_s` returns an empty string.

Comment: True and come to think of it he didn't serve a nil at all. He served nothing or, if you want, a non existing attribute.